# Frozen rows in WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

Does anyone have some code that freezes rows on top in the WPF DataGrid, with Virtualization turned on? We see some code out there without Virtualization off, but we need it with Virtualization on.

some links which works only for non-virtualized DataGrid

[Freeze DataGrid Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756791/freeze-datagrid-row/10235923#10235923)

[scrollable gridview with fixed searched row in datagrid using wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12852743/scrollable-gridview-with-fixed-searched-row-in-datagrid-using-wpf/12853369#12853369)

[How does WPF DataGrid get frozen rows/columns working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774417/how-does-wpf-datagrid-get-frozen-rows-columns-working)