# Scrolling Below ColumnHeader in WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, scrollviewer

I am trying to get this single-column DataGrid to scroll when I hover over the grid and move the mouse wheel.

```
<Grid Height ="500" .....
<!-- ListCollectionView for sorting -->
<DataGrid Name="dgTable"  Style ="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle1}"
Grid.Row ="1" Grid.Column ="0"  
VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsLcv}"
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
SelectionMode="Single"
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
CanUserAddRows="False"
CanUserSortColumns="True"
HorizontalAlignment="Center"
Width="215" Height="500">

<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" SortMemberPath="descr"
IsReadOnly="True" 
CanUserSort="True" 
Binding="{Binding Path=descr, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=     PropertyChanged}"
Width ="215"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

This is the style for the DataGrid.

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="DataGrid">
<Setter Property="RowHeaderWidth" Value="0" />
  <Setter Property = "ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
  <Setter Property = "ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled" />
 </Style>
```

This is the Style for the ColumnHeader:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
<Setter Property="Height" Value="35" />
<Setter Property="SeparatorBrush" Value="#79858b" />
<Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Black" />
<Setter Property="Background" Value ="{DynamicResource Brush1}"/> 
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF60727B"/>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2,0,2,2"></Setter>
</Style>
```

When I placed the DataGrid inside a ScrollViewer tag, the scrolling worked, but the ColumnHeader disapppeared.  I need to keep the Columnheader for sorting.
I have reviewed SO posts about frozen rows, [Frozen rows in WPF DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731690/frozen-rows-in-wpf-datagrid).  I was hoping there is a simpler solution than using a lot of control templates on the ScrollViewer components.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: The DataGrid has its own scrolling that works the way you want. Get rid of the ScrollViewer, and set the DataGrid's `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`. Not `VerticalContentAlignment`, that's a different property.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGrid` has its own scrolling that works the way you want.

Try getting rid of the `ScrollViewer`, and set the DataGrid's `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`. Not `VerticalContentAlignment`, that's a different property.

XAML layout is a maze of twisty little properties, all alike, except they're all different.